# Sprites Not Moving When Added to Group in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, 2d-games

I am using phaser3. When I create a group of sprites with values for gravity they are not moving. If the sprites are created individually then they do move.

For example, the code below works:

```
  brick1 = game.add.sprite(game.world.width / 2, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
  brick2 = game.add.sprite((game.world.width / 2) + 60, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
  game.physics.arcade.enable(brick1);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(brick2);
  brick1.enableBody=true;
  brick2.enableBody=true;
  brick1.body.gravity.y = 10;
  brick2.body.gravity.y = 10;
```

I need them to be in a group so if I have the code below, they just don't move. I have checked the attributes on each child item and they have values for gravity.

```
      brick = game.add.group();
  brick1 = brick.create(game.world.width / 2, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
  brick2 = brick.create((game.world.width / 2)+60, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
  game.physics.arcade.enable(brick);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(brick1);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(brick2);
  brick1.enableBody=true;
  brick2.enableBody=true;
  brick1.body.gravity.y = 10;
  brick2.body.gravity.y = 10;
  console.log(brick);
```

**UPDATE:**

I realise that this is happening when setting the velocity of each child in the group. I want to have the user press the down cursor key and then change the velocity. I have the code below, but this just stops them from moving at all.

```
  if (!cursors.down.isDown) {
    brick.children.forEach(child => child.body.setVelocity(300));
  } else {
    brick.children.forEach(child => child.body.setVelocity(300));
  }
```

Also tried with "brick.children.forEach(child => child.body.velocity = 300);", but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make your code working with as few corrections as possible. I guess variable `game` in your example points to the current scene, so i called it scene:

```
    let brick = scene.add.group();
    let brick1 = brick.create(game.world.width / 2, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
    let brick2 = brick.create((game.world.width / 2)+60, 0, 'tile'+randomNumber(1,6));
    scene.physics.add.existing(brick1);
    scene.physics.add.existing(brick2);
    brick1.enableBody=true;
    brick2.enableBody=true;
    brick1.body.gravity.y = 10;
    brick2.body.gravity.y = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was a long time ago. Eventually, I finished the game and got it working, but it went through so many revisions, it would by very hard to find out now what was done. Is it best for me to now delete this question?

Comment: I think your question could be useful for others and should not be deleted.

Comment: Hi, I will try to dig out the code which worked and post it on here. Please bear with me as it was a long time ago and might be difficult to find.